# Multiple Data Transfer Objects for multiple layers

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I have recently looked at an application, which uses the Model View Presenter pattern in the User Interface layer.  There are Model classes like this:

```
Public Class OrderModel
        Public Property OrderId() As Integer
        Public Property OrderDate() As Date
        Public Property RequiredDate() As Date
        Public Property Freight() As Single    
        Public Property OrderDetails() As IList(Of OrderDetailModel)
        Public Property Member() As MemberModel
    End Class
```

In the Domain layer, there are domain classes like this:

```
Public Class Order
        Inherits BusinessObject
        Public Property OrderId() As Integer
        Public Property OrderDate() As Date
        Public Property RequiredDate() As Date
        Public Property Freight() As Double
        Public Property Member() As Member
        Public Property OrderDetails() As List(Of OrderDetail)
    End Class
```

Notice that Order and OrderModel are identical.  There is a class called Model.vb in the UI layer, which has lots of code like this:

```
Return Mapper.Map(Of List(Of Member), List(Of MemberModel))(members)
```

Is it good practice to have two different Data Transfer Objects for each entity in the database? i.e. one DTO in the User Interface (OrderModel) and one in the model (Order) or is it better to have one DTO per entity for both layers eliminating the need to have the Mapper code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make right decision you should compare responsibilities of models in the User Interface layer and in the Domain layer.

> Is it good practice to have two different Data Transfer Objects for each entity in the database? i.e. one DTO in the User Interface (OrderModel) and one in the model (Order) ...

It is quite common approach when people practice [Domain-Driven Design](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/domain-driven-design/info). They have Domain Model that knows nothing about presentation (e.g. Order) and View Models (e.g. OrderModel) that are placed in presentation layer.

> ... or is it better to have one DTO per entity for both layers eliminating the need to have the Mapper code?

If your application is simple enough and your `Order` is simply DTO that is data container only and has no behaviour, you may have only one layer with DTOs.

**Edit:**
There is a quote from [12 ASP.NET MVC Best Practices](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/10/27/12-asp.net-mvc-best-practices.aspx) article about working with DomainModel and ViewModels.

> Model’s Best Practices
>
> 7 – DomainModel != ViewModel
>
> The DomainModel represents the domain, while the ViewModel is designed around the needs of the View, and these two worlds might be (and usually are) different. Furthermore the DomainModel is data plus behaviours, is hierarchical and is made of complex types, while the ViewModel is just a DTO, flat, and made of strings. To remove the tedious and error-prone object-mapping code, you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). For a nice overview of the various options I recommend you read: [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx).